# Handle Request payload using HTTPX for post data and capcha key to google recapchaV2

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, recaptcha, httpx

I'm trying to send the key I got from anti captcha, an example of the key is like this

```json
{
    "errorId":0,
    "status":"ready",
    "solution":
    {
        "gRecaptchaResponse":"3AHJ_VuvYIBNBW5yyv0zRYJ75VkOKvhKj9_xGBJKnQimF72rfoq3Iy-DyGHMwLAo6a3"
    },
    "cost":"0.001500",
    "ip":"46.98.54.221",
    "createTime":1472205564,
    "endTime":1472205570,
    "solveCount":"0"
}
```

I'm trying to send the value in the g-response key (it contains bypass capcha) but I don't know how to send a payload request to the Recaptcha URL, the network description is like this

[image: recapcha network]

these are the headers for the captcha,

[image: headers and method for capcha URL]

I want to use the key that I got from anticapcha to bypass, then I make a request for data search after the capcha has been bypassed, my code is like this

```py
class Locator(object):
    """class to find school locator"""

    def __init__(
        self,
        url: Optional[str] = "https://mybaragar.com/index.cfm?",
        params: Optional[dict[str, Any]] = None,
        headers: Optional[dict[str, Any]] = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        },
        api_key: Optional[str] = None,
        website_key: Optional[str] = None,
    ):
        self.url: str = url
        self.params: dict[str, Any] = params
        self.headers: dict[str, Any] = headers
        self.solver = recaptchaV2Proxyless()

        # solver setup
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.website_key = website_key
        self.client = Client()

    def solve_captcha(self, sitekey: str):
        """resolve captcha v2 

        Args:
            sitekey (str): website key for bypass capcha
        """
        headers: dict = {
            "content-type": "application/x-protobuffer",
            "cookie": "__Secure-3PSID=SgjFUgcMhK-HVyybbLH0riteaGdyRWxselnkRXWJxq2rjwyvYXp3pavZE0ePt1obNzd12Q.; __Secure-3PAPISID=Y_7wkodD5a0ZuHN4/Ar2CPyucPiF7dfJA0; NID=511=s-gIuV4uvQNKsfuPUm6Z41MVf8EMHdBeCD0ydgE1o6bGIQ8JE0LHu2GagudzwTjPdCfI78TASrrK6Xq9XGzk6lVaLgvNl6I9SNQ5MaVQr2hDj75FqZozXKgYYAdBAMUc-6wi1xI89i6HazvhC_7SyvajPmbXdD8J6rob43zrjlERiPshgiV8oozdvh16VdSrGQzZfWYNxqFFN95iEMo6BAXj_iEWnaRv_7vWw5oHKYcvnK3B7w_-p3C2477AXkUCEmMzRCDLlzRJjWhQ78XJD5IixMImsXmYJyGMKpkUz7gPns358uq5_bSB1WjG72fuFr9YK6XT_CqoIbLaxW1a7EWeegUjGDaXkNRCwvCvzkcMqkqLaOcT6lhqxAVWTgkT64hQX5HAr1kLd2j2Of8gZozSWqsPhaGQmCwOi4jTFxzR9B_SKVQxBBTDEMPk7XPDVeRrviwOPJJAwW55AInDpkY2Tx789-jYhpUn3t--japlkbZzpjInu6GX_wXK7ABSMRVSfpeFIQky62f-BroPYLQkU8JalDmVnQ_9gO3HsKlx1pvxV96aXNkaYu9WdW0PJ8MKc__whIenFw; __Secure-3PSIDCC=AIKkIs2ZZCAwmd6CAU2iZePJJjBhda6W0UW1jQ9rQ3phpRz_zUnE3H4cXYZRAetQu1dHi34gM6Ga",
            "origin": "https://www.google.com",
            "referer": "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&v=Gg72x2_SHmxi8X0BLo33HMpr&k=6LelzS8UAAAAAGSL60ADV5rcEtK0x0lRsHmrtm62",
            "sec-ch-ua": '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": "macOS",
            "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
            "ec-fetch-site":"same-origin",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
            "x-client-data": ""
        }

        response = self.client.post(url, headers=headers)
        print(response.text)

        

    def parse(self):
        soup = self.client.get(url=self.url, params=self.params,)
        index_url = soup.css_first("form#SLSearchForm[action]").attrs["action"]
        base_url = "https://mybaragar.com/{}".format(index_url)
        
        

    def search(self, update: bool = False):
        searcher: SearchGenerator = SearchGenerator(
            search_url="https://geographic.org/streetview/canada/bc/west_vancouver.html",
            update_data=update,
        )
        reports = searcher.report()
        df = pd.read_csv(reports)
        datas = df.to_dict()
```

can anyone help?,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything regarding reload / verify post. That's will be handled by the anticaptcha team.

You should use the response from the anticaptcha library for submitting data into the target site, not recaptcha's verify or reload endpoint.